# Why is my function returning "function" and not an integer result?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following function:

```
viewModel.unreadCount = ko.dependentObservable(function() {   
    var unreadCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i x< xxxxxxxxxxxx.length; i++) {
        if (xxxxxx == false) {
            unreadCount++;
        }
    }

    return unreadCount;
}, viewModel);
```

When I use this in KnockoutJS, I can't do a simple `if (viewModel.unreadCount()==0)`, like this:

```html
<div data-bind="visible: viewModel.unreadCount()==0">
```

It turns out because when I run:

```html
<p>${ (typeof viewModel.unreadCount) }</p>
```

I get "function".

Any ideas why that is and how I can get it to return an INT so I can do an if statement?

Comment: `ko.dependentObservable()` returns a function, not the return value of the anonymous function you pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ko.dependentObservable()` is returning a function, as [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) pointed out, you should be able to call the function it returns by using this somewhat odd-looking syntax:

```
<div data-bind="visible: (viewModel.unreadCount)()==0">
```

This will then perform function application on the function that is returned, rather than just the `unreadCount` member of `viewModel`.